# How do I report scam phone calls?

Tags: phone, fraud, scam

I get scam phone calls on a regular basis. The latest one was a computer-generated voice claiming to be a security expert from Microsoft and alleging "errors and fraudulent behavior" within my computer network, ultimately threatening to file a police report yada yada yada call me back at number.

Anyway, I know how to handle the phone calls, but I'd very much like to help people fight them, or at least identify them.

[USA.gov](https://www.usa.gov/stop-scams-frauds) links to the [FCC Consumer Complaints website](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov), which led me to filling out a prohibitively lengthy and detailed report that seems like they'll end up getting in contact with me about it and also seems to be more about telemarketing than full-blown phone scams. A ddg search for "report a scam phone call" leads to the [FTC](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0076-phone-scams) which has a much more user friendly reporting system and [reportthecall.com](https://reportthecall.com/) which seems independent of any government agencies.

I called the number in the recording to verify it. A man with a non-American accent answered claiming to be some security agency. I, probably against my better judgement, simply said "You're a straight fraudster and I've got your number." and then went to report the number and the call and began to wonder: where?

With all 3 of these reporting sites, which one should I go with? What's SOP? And why is this not easier?

Comment: "Non-American accent"? The US is the 3rd most populous nation on the planet with citizens from almost every language group on the planet living in it. I'm thinking that you might want to re-phrase that part ...

Comment: In the end, I'm not sure that this is a security question. It is also very localised to the US, because we cannot list every place in the world people can report calls to. It also seems that you *have* your answer. I think the generic answer is to report to local law enforcement and to report to your phone carrier.